# Unity editor freezes upon entering play mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently programming my first game, a zombie shooter. I have a **WaveManager** script, which changes the waves and also increases the number of zombies per round. I have quite a few scripts, and all of them work fine. Just...when the **WaveManager** component is activated and I run the game, Unity freezes. It doesn't crash, just doesn't react. When I deactivate it, everything works fine. I could solve this problem if I had an error message, but I don't get one because Unity freezes. For context: I have 16GB ram and the M1 Silicon chip. This is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int targetsSpawned;
    public int targetsLeft;
    public int wave;
    public int firstWaveTargets;
    ZombieSoawner spawner;

    void Awake()
    {
        spawner = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("TargetSpawner").GetComponent<ZombieSoawner>();
        wave = 1;
        targetsSpawned = firstWaveTargets;
        targetsLeft = targetsSpawned;
        spawner.SpawnZombies();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (targetsLeft <= 0)
        {
            nextWave();
        }
    }

    void nextWave()
    {
            wave += 1;
            targetsSpawned += 2;
            targetsLeft = targetsSpawned;
            spawner.SpawnZombies();
    }
}
```

Some of the variables, like targetsLeft and targetsSpawned are accessed by other scripts. But everything is refrenced. And yes, the script is called TargetSoawner. I made a mistake while writing. Thanks for reading and for helping! This is my first question on the forum.

Oh, and I got some questions. Here is the rest:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieSoawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WaveManager manager;
    int targetsPlaced;
    public GameObject target;

    public void SpawnZombies()
    {
        while (manager.targetsSpawned > targetsPlaced)
        {
            PlaceTargets();
            targetsPlaced += 1;
        }
    }

    public void PlaceTargets()
    {
        targetsPlaced = 0;
        Vector3 originalPos = transform.localPosition;
        transform.localPosition = originalPos;
        float randomOffset = Random.Range(-20f, 20f);
        Vector3 randomPos = new Vector3(originalPos.x + randomOffset, originalPos.y + 5f, originalPos.z + randomOffset);
        Instantiate(target, randomPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

And the script for the target:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 50f;
    public float lookRadius = 20f;
    Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    WaveManager manager;

    private void Awake()
    {
        manager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("WaveManager").GetComponent<WaveManager>();
        target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

        if ( distance <= lookRadius)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(target.position);

            if (distance <= agent.stoppingDistance)
            {
                FaceTarget();
            }
        }
    }

    void FaceTarget()
    {
        Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
        if (health <= 0f)
        {
            manager.targetsLeft -= 1;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, lookRadius);
    }

}
```

Thanks @JeffRSon!
Yes, I put targetsPlaced = 0; in targets. Now I placed it inside SpawnZombies(), before PlaceTargets gets called.
Now it works just fine. I guess it really was an infinte loop.
Thanks!

Oh yeah, also, the correct ZombieSoawner looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieSoawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WaveManager manager;
    int targetsPlaced;
    public GameObject target;

    public void SpawnZombies()
    {
        targetsPlaced = 0;
        while (manager.targetsSpawned > targetsPlaced)
        {
            PlaceTargets();
            targetsPlaced += 1;
        }
    }

    public void PlaceTargets()
    {
        Vector3 originalPos = transform.localPosition;
        transform.localPosition = originalPos;
        float randomOffset = Random.Range(-20f, 20f);
        Vector3 randomPos = new Vector3(originalPos.x + randomOffset, originalPos.y + 5f, originalPos.z + randomOffset);
        Instantiate(target, randomPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

@JeffRSon said:

> targetsPlaced = 0 in PlaceTargets looks suspiscious given the while condition.

Comment: You probably have an infinite loop somewhere. I don't see how `targetsLeft` ever decreases in this code so you may just be spawning every frame in Update, forever.

Comment: If there is a `while` loop, that is likely the culprit.  Please include the function `SpawnZombies`.

Comment: The `Awake()` method instantly calls the `.SpawnZombies()` method of your `TargetSoawner`. Chances are the culprint might actually be that `.SpawnZombies()` method. Please could you edit your post to show the `.SpawnZombies()` method?

Comment: `targetsPlaced = 0` in `PlaceTargets` looks suspiscious given the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

Within `PlaceTargets` you continuously reset

```
targetsPlaced = 0;
```

so the

```
while (manager.targetsSpawned > targetsPlaced)
{
    PlaceTargets();
    targetsPlaced += 1;
}
```

will never finish.

Way saver would be to use a `for` loop with an exact pre-defined amount

```
public void SpawnZombies(int amount)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        PlaceTargets();
    }
}
```

And in the manager call it via

```
spawner.SpawnZombies(targetsSpawned);
```

This also solves your architecture issue of having circular dependencies between your two classes.

---

Further your `PlaceTargets` can be simplified a lot:

```
private void PlaceTargets()
{
    var randomOffset = Random.insideUnitCircle * 20f;
    Vector3 randomPos = transform.position + new Vector3( randomOffset.x, 5f, randomOffset.y);
    Instantiate(target, randomPos, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

which also correctly allows for different random in X and Z axis instead of always being on the same diagonal.

---

In order to reduce dependencies even more I would let the `Target` class itself keep track of currently alive instances and do e.g.

```
public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static HasSet<Target> instances = new();

    public int AliveTargets => instances.Count;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instances.Add(this);

        ...
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        instances.Remove(this);

        ...
    }
}
```

=> this class does not need to know the manager at all. And the manager can simply check for

```
if(Target.AliveTargets == 0)
{
    nextWave();
}
```

In theory you could even extend on this and go event-driven and instead of poll checking the amount rather check it only once everytime a target dies.